# How to stop/pause an activity in watch from mobile?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am currently starting an activity in watch from mobile by clicking a button. I am using wearable listener service to do it. Once the activity is started, the user performs gestures which are recognized and sent to mobile. So at some point in time, I want the user to click a button in mobile to close/pause this activity in watch. How can I do it? Should I destroy it or pause it? What should be my approach? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the message telling to close app in watch from phone,you can cancel all running work and close all activities in watch app  or call `System.exit(0)`.